# How to prove the follwing inequality

Tags: inequality

> If $$(a+b+c)abc=3$$
>   and $$a,b,c > 0$$
>   prove that $$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\geq 8$$

I can fairly easily prove that 
$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\geq8abc$,
but then I get stuck.....since then I cannot move forward

If I was to prove that $abc\geq1$ this would have been easy but I am stuck, please help me.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

edit:I am incredibly sorry that I remembered the question incorrectly

Comment: Actually, it is $abc \le1$ which you can see as follows: $3 = abc (a+b+c) \ge 3  (abc)^{4/3}$ (by AM-GM) which is $abc \le 1$.

Comment: ya I know $abc\leq1$ ,I was saying that if it was $abc\geq1$ this would have been an easy problem,but now I am stuck.

Comment: change of variable $a^2bc$ and others respectively may help

Comment: @Bijayan Ray intresting ,can you elaborate?I don't see the profit,except that our if statementreduces to a'+b'+c'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note:  $3=abc(a+b+c)\ge 3(abc)^{4/3}$ (by AM-GM) hence $ abc\le 1$.

Using this we have, using AM-GM again:
$$(a+b)(a+c)(b+c) = (a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc) - abc\\
\ge  3 (a+b+c)\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2} - 1\\
 = 9 (abc)^{-1/3} - 1\\
\ge 9-1 = 8$$

Comment: Thanks!!!This solution is actually really mind blowingly simple and clever at the same time!!!that second step(introduction of inequality) and also the third step is actually really elegant!

Comment: If you find the solution appropriate I'd be happy if you actually accept it.

Comment: Is that the tick mark thingy??sorry I didn't knew about that

Comment: Yes that's it. Thanks for accepting!